# Copy and paste a comment in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I copy and paste a comment in MS Word, including the name of the author of the comment? I tried copying and pasting the old fashioned way, but it only pastes the comment text, and not the author's details.

Comment: Is taking a screenshot acceptable? Where are you trying to paste it to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something that, by design I believe, isn't straightforward to do. After all, if the person who inserted a comment is someone other than you, you're not meant to pass off comments that that person didn't insert as his/her own.

Still, it can be done.

1. Copy the entire string of highlighted text that the comment is anchored to ('fringilla ultricies orci' in the following screenshot).

   [image: Original comment]
2. Determine the string of text that you want to use as the anchor text for the duplicate comment ('Pellentesque magna arcu' in the following screenshot), and paste the clipboard contents after the last character of that string.

   [image: Copy of comment pasted in new location]
3. Select the string that you want to use as the new anchor text, cut, select all the duplicate anchor text except the first and last characters, and paste. All the new anchor text will appear between the first and last characters of the original anchor text.

   [image: New anchor text + first and last letters of original anchor text]
4. Delete the first and last characters of the original anchor text.

   [image: Completed duplicate comment]

If you try to select and paste over all the anchor text at once, the comment is deleted too.

I obscured the commenter names in the screenshots, but they show up as being by the person who inserted the original comment, not by me.